# Graficar dos ´labels' para un mismo eje en Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Estoy realizando un análisis de datos a partir de un Dataframe y necesito realizar un climograma, el cual es un gráfico en el cual los meses del año se sitúan en el eje horizontal, mientras que en el eje vertical se representan en el eje de la izquierda las temperaturas medias mensuales mediante puntos unidos por una línea, mientras que en el eje de la derecha, y mediante barras, se representan las precipitaciones medias mensuales. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para para generar las dos 'labels' de temperatura y precipitación en el eje y?

A continuación dejo un ejemplo de cómo es un climograma y los datos del Dataframe que estoy utilizando:

[image: Climograma]

```
precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_5=pd.merge(precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_3.reset_index(), precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_4.reset_index())
precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_5.set_index('Mes',inplace=True)
print(precipitación_y_temperatura_promedio_Medellín_5)

             Precipitación Promedio (mm)  Temperatura Promedio (°C)
Mes                                                               
Enero                              63.2                       22.4
Febrero                            81.4                       22.7
Marzo                             129.1                       22.7
Abril                             170.7                       22.4
Mayo                              213.5                       22.6
Junio                             149.4                       22.9
Julio                             133.1                       23.1
Agosto                            139.7                       23.1
Septiembre                        181.8                       22.4
Octubre                           226.7                       21.8
Noviembre                         158.9                       21.8
Diciembre                         104.8                       21.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los datos para reproducir el ejemplo:

```
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
Mes,Precipitación Promedio(mm),Temperatura Promedio (°C)
Enero,63.2,22.4
Febrero,81.4,22.7
Marzo,129.1,22.7
Abril,170.7,22.4
Mayo,213.5,22.6
Junio,149.4,22.9
Julio,133.1,23.1
Agosto,139.7,23.1
Septiembre,181.8,22.4
Octubre,226.7,21.8
Noviembre,158.9,21.8
Diciembre,104.8,21.9
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col="Mes")
```

No puedes usar el mismo eje porque por definición compartirían marcas, escala y etiquetas en el eje <kbd>Y</kbd>, cosa que no queremos.
La clave está en usar [matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) para generar otra instancia de `Axes` pero compartiendo el eje <kbd>X</kbd> del anterior.

Luego cada uno se usa para una de las gráficas. Como el eje generado por `twinx` se superpone al anterior, se debe usar para las temperaturas, cambiando las etiquetas y marcas de ambos Axes al lado opuesto cada uno. De ésta forma nos evitamos recurrir a modificar la transparencia que siempre queda mal.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

df["Temperatura Promedio (°C)"].plot(color="red", ax=ax2, lw=2)
df["Precipitación Promedio(mm)"].plot(kind='bar', width=0.9,  ax=ax1)

ax2.set_ylim(0,  40)
ax1.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position("left")
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

fig.suptitle("Medellin")
ax2.set_ylabel("Temperatura Promedio (°C)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Precipitación Promedio (mm)")

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]